# Qt Application : How to create standalone executable file for all Ubuntu machine?

Tags: c++, qt

Thanks in advance.

I developed a Qt c++ application using Qt 5.12.3. Then using linuxdeployqt-6-x86_64.AppImage i am able to run executable anywhere in the same machine(where application was developed). But i am unable to run the application in other ubuntu machine having different version of Qt and non-qt ubuntu machine.

I read about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` .But for non-qt pc it won't be helpful.
I tried **Debreate** tool to create deb package of my application. I failed.

I want my application to run in all ubuntu machine (atleast having same configuration as my machine - 64bit).

I am getting following error in other machine like

> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5*: version `Qt_5' not found"

So shall i need to change libs in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or some other tricks are there? or shall i change my pro file?

Please help. I am struggling since last 5 days.

Any hints will be helpful.

I tried "https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html". But the page is very confuging and not clear.

Comment: What did you not understand on the qt.io page?

Comment: The "ldd ./application" output is "libQt5SerialPort.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found". I have libQt5SerialPort.so.5 : Qt_5 version in parent machine(where application was developed). This error may be  due to qt version mismatch. All libraries are present in executable directory. But how to link all libraries in the parent machine, so that it will not give error in child machine.

Comment: I will recommend making a staticly linked application to make your life easier. Otherwise, you will need the [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) app, which will collect most of the necessary libs into the result directory

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried linuxdeployqt as per "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDzlT_ODpM8" . But issue is , it is working in same machine. It is not working in other ubuntu machine.

Comment: You have a static linked Qt5 version? Have you used qmake to build your application with `config+=static` ?

Comment: I will try this now and post the result.

Comment: i added CONFIG += static , to the project pro file and re-build using linuxdeployqt tool. Now getting the error as : ERROR: ldd outputLine: "libodbc.so.2 => not found"
ERROR: for binary: "/home/user/Qt/5.12.3/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlodbc.so" in the parent machine. The "libodbc.so.2" is found no where.

Comment: @user3427258 If you want to build a static executable you need static versions of all bundled libraries.

Comment: I went through google and all i tried. But nothing worked for me. Is there any software available for ubuntu, which will take all required inputs(source code,libraries,icons etc) and output will be one software bundle , which can be used in every ubuntu machine. In Windows machine i did this and its very easy. But for ubuntu machine i can't find this stuff. Please help me.